# How to pass a function in laravel view?

Tags: laravel-5

I have the following a Course Model with a function of trainers and I'm trying to pass it to the view so I can see the trainers for the course.

Here is my model function

```
public function trainers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'course_user');
}
```

This is my view where I'm trying to pass the Model Course and the function trainers.

```
<h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Trainer: {{$course->trainers()}}</h6>
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

`htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hs-03/re`sources/views/admin/courses/showCourse.blade.php)

Here is my controller:

```
    public function show($id)
    {
      $created_bies = \App\User::get()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.app_please_select'), '');
    $trainers = \App\User::get()->pluck('name', 'id');
    $tests = \App\Test::where('course_id', $id)->get();$lessons = \App\Lesson::where('course_id', $id)->get();
    // $date = Carbon::now();
    $date = Carbon::now()->addDays(30)->toFormattedDateString();
    $user = User::find(1);
    $user->name;

    $course = Course::findOrFail($id);

    return view('admin.courses.showCourse', compact('course', 'tests', 'lessons', 'date', 'user'));
}
```

Comment: Share your controller code.

Comment: In your view file $course->trainers() its object you can't print that like this. It would have multiple ojects.

Comment: I think I need something like {{$course->trainers()->get()}} since I'm getting the data but I have no idea how to get just the name. This get me everything Trainer: [{"id":4,"name":"Eddy Murphy","email":"murphy@admin.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2019-03-03 13:40:58","updated_at":"2019-03-03 13:40:58","created_by_id":1,"pivot":{"course_id":54,"user_id":4}}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the `trainers` methods isn't return a String. The method like It is define in your Model is Supposed to return a  `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany` object like you can see [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_belongsToMany). The error is because your are trying to show that object directly within your template as a String which is not possible. I suppose you want to show some thing like number of trainers. Which you can get like

```
<h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Trainer: {{$course->trainers()->count()}}</h6>
```

This is possible because the `count` method return an integer and not a object like `trainers`.

On another hand If you want to stick to that usage, you must insert a loop within your view which will walk through the collection of trainers which is being return by the call to `$course->trainers()`

```
@foreach($course->trainers() as $trainer)
    <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Trainer: {{$trainer->name }}</h6>
@endforeach
```

Comment: looping worked, I was using the wrong naming conventions. Thanks so much

Comment: You are Welcome